# One Equation Implying The Another .

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

Suppose that $\{W_t\}$ and $\{Z_t\}$ are independent and identically distributed sequences , with 
$$P(W_t=0)=P(W_t=1)=.5$$ 
$$P(Z_t=-1)=P(Z_t=1)=.5$$ .

Define $$X_t=W_{t}(1-W_{t-1})Z_t$$

Now it is written that :

> $X_{t-1}=1$ implies that $W_{t-1}=1$ , which implies that $X_t=0$ .

- I have not understood how does $X_{t-1}=1$ imply $W_{t-1}=1$ and that imply $X_t=0$ ?

Also it is written :

$P(X_{t-1}=1,X_t=1)=0$ .

- How is the probability  derived ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $X_{t-1} = 1 = W_{t-1}(1-W_{t-2})Z_{t-1}$. For this to be true, we must have $W_{t-1} = 1$, because if it was zero the RHS would be zero. Now, because $X_t = W_t(1-W_{t-1})Z_t$, and we know that $W_{t-1} = 1$, plugging it in shows us that $X_t = 0$.

In addition, because $X_{t-1}$ being one forces $X_t$ to be zero, it follows that $P(X_{t-1}=1, X_t=1)$ is zero.

Comment: But how does $W_{t-1}=1$ imply  $W_{t-2}=0$ , because if   $W_{t-2}=1$ then $X_{t-1}$ CANNOT BE equal to $1$ .

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit that how $P(X_{t-1}=1)P(X_{t}=1)=1/64$ ?

Comment: Because the first problem involved showing that if $X_{t-1} = 1$, then $X_t = 0$. It follows that $P(X_{t-1}=1, X_t = 0) = 1$. That's why $P(X_{t-1}=1, X_t = 1) = 0$.

Comment: But how can I compute single probability , such as , $P(X_{t-1}=1)$ ?

Comment: We have $X_t = 1$ only if $W_{t-1}=0, W_t = 1$, and $Z_t = 1$. Since the probability of each of these is $0.5$, it follows that $P(X_{t-1} = 1)=0.5 \cdot 0.5 \cdot 0.5 = 1/8$. That's where the $1/64$ comes from.